# Terminate last execution using script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have been testing a script for nearly 24 hours, the idea was that if certain cells were edited within the sheet, then the trigger would wait 5 minutes before resetting the values within those cells.

However when testing it became apparent that with many people using this sheet, the trigger was executing many times and sometimes the data edited by a user would reset within seconds because of a earlier execution.

To combat this I thought of putting a few lines of script in there, to cancel any previous executions of this function that is still running.

However with being a newbie to script and not having the knowledge I hope to gain, finding the information to start that script is proving difficult.

This is what I have so far

```
function RESET(e) {
   const ar = e.range;
   const as = ar.getSheet();
   const cells = ["B3","E3"]; // add cells you want to be edited to activate the script
   // if C3 or E3 is edited, wait for 300 seconds
   if (as.getName()=="Gauge" && cells.includes(ar.getA1Notation())){
        Utilities.sleep(300000);
        as.getRange("B3").setValue("ALL");
        as.getRange("E3").setValue("ALL");
   }
}
```

Comment: You want the shared sheet to update every 5 minutes following a start point which is common? (Say every 5 mins after 3pm) or how? Can you explain more ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a document lock][1](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock) to guard the RESET function running at the same time for multiple users, but this will probably lead to timeouts.
A better approach would be to create a [time-driven trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable?hl=en#time-driven_triggers) with a delay of 5 minutes inside the RESET function. When it fires, clear the values in B3/E3 or do any other work required.

Make sure that you clear previous triggers before you create new one, so that at any time only single trigger is active. If there is no user activity for 5 minutes, it will eventually run.

```
const SHEET = "Gauge"

// make sure to create as onEdit installable trigger, not a simple trigger    
function onInstallableEdit(e) {
   const ar = e.range;
   const as = ar.getSheet();
   const cells = ["B3","E3"]; // add cells you want to be edited to activate the script
   // if C3 or E3 is edited, wait for 300 seconds
   if (as.getName()==SHEET && cells.includes(ar.getA1Notation())){
     const lock = LockService.getDocumentLock()
     try{
      lock.waitLock(10000)
      // delete previous triggers, if any
      ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().filter(t=>t.getHandlerFunction()===myHandler.name).forEach(t=>ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(t))
      // create new trigger to be fired after 5 minutes
      ScriptApp.newTrigger(myHandler.name).timeBased().after(5*60*1000).create()
     } catch(e){
       console.warn(e)
     }
   }
}

function myHandler(){
  const as = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(SHEET)
  as.getRange("B3").setValue("ALL");
  as.getRange("E3").setValue("ALL");
}
```

Comment: I do not want to lock the cells, as I still want users to be able to change the data within those two cells. and the only issue with the timed trigger is the fact it would have to run every minute, and my fear is with other scripts running in the background and a wide variety of formulas within the sheet itself, this would lead to the spreadsheet slowing down. The ideal solution would be if there was a way to tell the previous execution of that function to terminate

Comment: placing the lock does not lock the cells, it just locks the code and prevents the code to be run at once. Think of it like a tool to force the code to be run in parallel, or fail if the lock times out.
timed trigger must not run every minute. You should create one-of trigger that will run once, after 5 minutes delay

Comment: That sounds ideal in that case, however the code you so kindly supplied does not work, it seems to run and then immediately completes without adjusting the cells.

Comment: I looked at the new trigger it creates, and the specific time for it to run is 5 hours previous, so I have amended the code so that it runs 5 minutes later by adjusting the time in milliseconds, however the trigger it creates never seems to execute, I have created a test sheet with no sensitive data in to test the script before moving it into my working sheet, would it help if I was to share that with you? if you do manage to find the issue, would you talk me through it, as I want to learn as much as I can about building scripts.

Comment: exactly, the code in onInstallableEdit does not change the cells, it just creates the trigger. When the trigger runs (after 5 minutes), myHandler is called and the cells in B3 and E3 are then updated.
Check the script Oauth scopes, try to run myHandler directly and see if it works. Check the logs if it does not

Comment: If i create the myHandler trigger manually it fires without issue, but when I run it as part of the script, it creates the trigger but never fires it, after a period of time the trigger will say disabled. Oauth scopes seem fine, but there are no logs as it has not fired.

Comment: have you set onInstallableEdit as installable trigger?

Comment: Yes I have set the onIstallableEdit as installable trigger, and like I say it creates the myHandler trigger but it never fires, after a period of time it disables without ever firing.

Comment: Can you run the myHandler() manually? Try to debug the methods, this concept works for sure. Try to increase the delay and check the trigger, be patient. Break the problem into smaller pieces and try to determine the root cause

Comment: Whilst in the script I can press run or debug on myHandler and it fires without issue, doing exactly what I want it to do, I can create a trigger for myHandler and set the date and time for five minutes from now and it fires without issue, however when using it as part of this script it schedules the trigger correctly for the time needed, but it does not fire,

Comment: I do not get an error, or a log because it never fired all that happens is within an hour after it should of fired when looking at the installed triggers it shows as disabled, when I click on the informational icon it says "This trigger was disabled for an unknown reason"

Comment: Try to create a time trigger manually.
Also check to see if you hit any of the quotas https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas. If there are too many updates, you might hit the quota and deleting/creating a trigger each time is not the best solution. You may want to create a single trigger that will run periodically every 5 minutes and implement a logic that will check to see if it is time to update the cell contents immediately, or do it on the next hit (in 5 minutes).

Comment: Like I say I have created it manually and it works, I cant have hit the quota as I'm only using it on a test sheet at the moment, I have been doing some research and it seems there is a known issue creating timed triggers within a script

Comment: @DanielLawrie did this solution work for you?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I am still playing with the code to try and make it work for me.